# Error with Cats and Dog Convolutional Network: model.fit_generator

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, python-3.7

I'm using a PDF to build my first Convolutional Nerual Network using cats and dogs and am encountering a consistent error. The text is: WARNING:tensorflow:sample_weight modes were
coerced from
  ...
    to
  ['...']
WARNING:tensorflow:sample_weight modes were coerced from
  ...
    to
  ['...']

The relevant code is pasted in two sections below. Any help would be appreciated because I'm hitting a wall in regards to this.

This top bit is working but may be relevant:

```
#Build the network

#Import needed layers and models from tensorflow.keras
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

#Build model--Use sequential value--Most common
model = models.Sequential()

#Input layer
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation = 'relu', 
                        input_shape = (150, 150, 3)))          
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2))

#First hidden layer
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2))

#Second hidden layer
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2))

#Third hidden layer
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2))

#Fourth hidden layer
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation = 'relu'))

#Output layer
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

#
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers

#Compilation step
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
             optimizer= 'adam',
             metrics=['acc'])

#Read images from directories
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

train_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_dir,
        target_size = (150, 150),
        batch_size = 20,
        class_mode = 'binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        validation_dir,
        target_size = (150, 150),
        batch_size = 20,
        class_mode = 'binary')
```

Fit model with a batch generator
This part of the code is what causes the error
    history = model.fit_generator(
            train_generator,
            steps_per_epoch = 100,
            epochs = 30,
            validation_data = validation_generator,
            validation_steps = 50)

As a final note, this code is in Python 3 and uses the kagglecatsanddogs database from Microsoft

Comment: Could you post the entire stack trace of the error? It may provide a clue as to which part of the code is throwing the error.

Comment: I'll try to post it in the morning. I'm having some trouble with adding text to the post.

Comment: @ipefaur: You can post the complete stack trace but I feel train_generator is being incorrectly assigned. It should be train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory instead of train_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory

Answer (score 0):

The below Warning is fixed in the Nightly Version of Tensorflow and will be included in the Next Stable Version, `Tensorflow 2.2`

```
WARNING:tensorflow:sample_weight modes were coerced from ... to
['...'] WARNING:tensorflow:sample_weight modes were coerced from ... to
['...']
```

Currently, to make if work, please install Tensorflow Nightly Version as shown below:

```
!pip install tf-nightly
```

For more details, please refer this [Github Issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/37500).